# .net framework 4 client profile with reference to .netframework 4 .dll

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm creating a WCF service which uses the .net framework 4 client profile dll.
when i attempt to compile the application with any reference to my other project (.net 4.0) i get a number of missing references errors.

by changing my WCF project to .net framework 4.0 what should i be aware off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> by changing my WCF project to .net framework 4.0 what should i be aware off?

That the full .NET 4.0 framework is installed on the machine you intend to run this service on. And that's pretty much all.